# How to properly render server-side errors in the client for Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, httprequest

I've setup a simple Node/Express service that creates new bookmarks to a database.

In my Bookmark schema, one of the fields, url, has validations. When you try to create a new bookmark without the correct validations, it throws an error and a message.

E.g. if you don't provide a url to the request, then it will throw a message `Please provide a url.`

The route for the POST request to create a new bookmark:

```
app.post(
    '/api/bookmarks',
    (req, res) => {
      const { url, tags } = req.body;

      const bookmark = new Bookmark({
        url,
        tags
      });

      bookmark.save()
        .then(res => {
          res.send(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("err:", error);
          res.status(400).send(error)
        });
    }
  );
```

What my Bookmark schema looks like:

```
const bookmarkSchema = new Schema({
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please provide a URL."],
    match: [urlRegex, "Your URL is invalid. Please make sure to add www."]
  },
  tags: [String]
});
```

When I make an API call on the front end client (e.g. via React), I am able to catch the error and subsequent message (`Please provide a URL.`), but as you can see, I have to call `err.response.data.errors.url.message` which seems very verbose and long winded.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/bookmarks', { tags: ["banana", "orange"] })
  .then(result => console.log('Result:', result.data))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err.response.data.errors.url.message));
```

What has me thinking - is there a better way to render errors here? Would it be better handle errors in the client side instead?

I'm quite new to error handling so would like to know what is considered best practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. So you don't have to check it in schema.

```js
app.post(
    '/api/bookmarks',
    (req, res) => {
      const { url, tags } = req.body;
      if (!url) {
        res.status(400).send({error: "URL is missing"})
        return;
      }
      if (!url.match(urlRegex) {
        res.status(400).send({error: "URL is not valid"})
        return;
      }
      const bookmark = new Bookmark({
        url,
        tags
      });

      bookmark.save()
        .then(res => {
          res.send(result)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("err:", error);
          res.status(500)
        });
    }
  );
```

It's a bad practice to send server side errors to frontend. It's a easy way to leak information about your database/backend. You should send your own string message instead of catched error.

Comment: I see. So in my POST route, instead of `res.status(400).send(error)` should I change it to `res.send({ error: "Some kind of error message." })`? And also, as you can see, my `url` field has two validations: 1 to make sure it's required, and 1 to make sure it is valid URL (checked using regex). How do I differentiate what error message to show depending on what validation error occurred then?

Comment: You can run your urlRegex before you create the new Bookmark
if (url.match(urlRegex) { 
  res.status(400).send({
    error: "Your URL is invalid. Please make sure to add www."
 })
}.
And not run the save() if url is not valid.

Comment: Ahh makes sense now! So I assume that I can remove the validation in schema? Or is it better to leave it in for safe measure? P.S. I assume you mean `if (!url.match(urlRegex)` in your code above?

Comment: Yeah you can remove them from schema. I would personally probably leave  required: true check on the schema. And yeah I meant (!url.match) good catch.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I disagree, leave them in the schema, that's where validation belongs and you can choose to handle a mongoose ValidationError subtype different from other error types.